# Access a PHP Array Passed from JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following structure passed from jquery to php. I can't seem to access the data within from PHP.

[image]

this is what I've been trying - php:

```
print_r($_POST['cropData']);   // this shows the above array

foreach($_POST['cropData'] as $i => $row) {
  echo "... $row['src'] ... $row['width'] ..."; 
}
```

I bet its the most simple thing - any advise how I can hook into the data in this array - must be the array or array factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your arrays are two levels deep. This *should* work:

```
foreach($_POST['cropData'] as $i => $row) {
        echo "... $row[0]['src'] ... $row[0]['width'] ...";   
}
```